# How can I access the precision touchpad pointer events releeased in edgeHTML 17

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, pointer-events, touchpad

I'm developing a game in canvas that interprets "wheel" events as a command to zoom in/out on the scene. I was playtesting in Edge on my laptop when I realized that Edge was not firing "wheel" events while 2-finger scrolling on my precision touchpad.

After a little searching, I came across [this official response from Microsoft](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/12/07/better-precision-touchpad-experience-ptp-pointer-events/) which states: 'Microsoft Edge will fire Pointer Events with a pointerType of “touch” in response to PTP gestures'.

The problem is that these pointer events don't appear to exist. I added event listeners for all the pointer events and told them to log the event if it had a pointer type of "touch" but got no response (though they were triggered by the touch screen as expected). What confuses me more, is there doesn't seem to be pointer event activity of any type while making 2-finger gestures. So am I missing some non-standard event type or something? I'm pretty sure I haven't misread the article since a response to the loss of "wheel" event functionality appears to be the whole point of the work around and so leaving out events for two-finger gestures would defeat the point.

Answer (score 2):

A few days later I tried again and managed to get ptp touch pointer events through

- pointerdown
- pointermove
- pointerup
- pointercancel
- pointerout

Side note, "touch" pointers seem to be identical to those generated by touching the touch screen so if you need them to be distinguished like I did, you can exploit the fact that ptp gestures do not fire touch events to distinguish them.